# Mocap animation is tilted only upon import into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mo-cap

I'm working with mocap animations (FBX) that I want to retarget on a Mixamo model in Unity. To start, I opened the animation in Blender and it looks fine (not tilted) -

[image]

But when I import in Unity and apply type humanoid to the rig, it comes in tilted / wonky -

[image]

[Video of tilted animation](https://www.loom.com/share/76173f911cad4e6ba286925d62177543?t=141&sid=87dee248-2844-4c91-9a53-7e272e691f2a)

I get these error messages in Unity:

[image]

Even after applying "Translation DoF" and changing animation type. Why is my animation coming in tilted and how can I fix this?